# Если имеются все возможные значения

Tags: sql, oracle

Приветствую. Имеются 3 таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо получить все номера кафдр, если кафедра преподает все специальности. Не могу понять как сделать такой запрос, пробовал с COUNT(), но не слишком успешно.

Comment: group by по номеру кафедры из каф_спец и в having count(1)=(select count(1) from спец)

Comment: Вы покажите хоть, что вы пробовали и где возникли затруднения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ном_каф
FROM каф_cпец
GROUP BY ном_каф
HAVING COUNT(ном_каф)=(SELECT COUNT(ном_спец) FROM спец)
```